# Simple Random generator generates blank item

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a random generator of text.

It works ok but a small issue that I can't seem to resolve is occurring.

When I click my test button, every now and then a blank item appears. Here is my code.

```
Dim rng As New System.Random()
    Dim RAND(16) As String
    RAND(0) = "A"
    RAND(1) = "B"
    RAND(2) = "C"
    RAND(3) = "D"
    RAND(4) = "E"
    RAND(5) = "F"
    RAND(6) = "G"
    RAND(7) = "H"
    RAND(8) = "I"
    RAND(9) = "J"
    RAND(10) = "K"
    RAND(11) = "L"
    RAND(12) = "M"
    RAND(13) = "N"
    RAND(14) = "O"
    RAND(15) = "P"
    TextBox1.Text = RAND(rng.Next(RAND.Count()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RAND(16) as declared contains 17 elements. Last one is blank, because you did not initialize it to anything. You can use a Watch window to verify:

[image]

Regarding how `Nothing` becomes a blank, it's a result of an implicit conversion behind the scenes.

Comment: God bless another pair of eyes. Thanks Neolisk. Appreciate the help.